# jQuery find next and prev element

Tags: jquery

I try to find a `next` or `prev` element of current element. But `next()` and `prev()` function can only work in a scope, it can not reach outside. For an example this is what I want to achieve:

```
<ul id="ul1">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>
    <ul id="ul2">
      <li>4</li>
      <li>
        <ul id="ul3">
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

If current element is `ul1`, next element is `<li>1</li>`, prev element is null.

If current element is `<li>1</li>`, next element is `<li>2</li>`, prev element is `ul1`

If current element is `<li>8</li>`, next element is `<li>9</li>`, prev element is `<li>7</li>`

Comment: and if current element `<li>3</li>` ? also `<li>4</li>` ??

Comment: @ifaour - no, it'd be the `<li>` that's the parent of `#ul2`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, this was a really neat problem.  Thanks for posting!

I accomplished this with a chained jQuery statement.  Only thing is, if you run `previous()` on the top `ul` you'll get `body`.  Which I think technically makes sense.  However, if this isn't the desired behavior, see my update below.

**Usage**: `next("#ul3")` returns `<li>5</li>`

Next:

```
function next(selector) {
    var $element = $(selector);

    return $element
        .children(":eq(0)")
        .add($element.next())
        .add($element.parents().filter(function() {
            return $(this).next().length > 0;
        }).next()).first();
}
```

Previous:

```
function previous(selector) {
    var $element = $(selector);

    return $element
        .prev().find("*:last")   
        .add($element.parent())    
        .add($element.prev())
        .last();     
}
```

**Update** If you want to limit the upper most node previous can be, you could do:

```
function previous(selector, root) {
    var $element = $(selector);

    return $element
        .prev().find("*:last")   
        .add($element.parent())     
        .add($element.prev())
        .last().not($(root).parent());      
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/n89dz/

**Another Update**: Here's a jQuery plugin for convenience:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.domNext = function() {
        return this
            .children(":eq(0)")
            .add(this.next())
            .add(this.parents().filter(function() {
                return $(this).next().length > 0;
            }).next()).first();        
    };

    $.fn.domPrevious = function() {
        return this
            .prev().find("*:last")   
            .add(this.parent())     
            .add(this.prev())
            .last();         
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Expanded example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/KzyAY/

Comment: It work perfect, I also create a snippet here http://jsfiddle.net/dqTkY/2/. Thankyou

Answer (score 5):

What an interesting problem! Sounds like you're flattening the recursive structure of HTML so that it's loop-able - I can see it coming in handy.

You can solve the problem by breaking `.next()` down into the following cases:

1. Element has children --> `next()` is the first child.
2. Element has no children, and is not the last child --> `next()` is the same as jQuery's `.next()`
3. Element has no children, is last child:

   1. Find closest parent that is not the last child --> `next()` is that parent's next sibling
   2. If no such parent exists --> `next()` is `null`

Code would be (calling it `flatNext` to preserve original jQuery `.next` behaviour):

```
$.fn.flatNext = function () {
   if (this.children().length) return this.children().eq(0);
   if (!this.is(":last-child")) return this.next();
   if (this.closest(":not(:last-child)").length)
       return this.closest(":not(:last-child)").next();
   return $([]); // Return empty jQuery object rather than null
};
```

And `$.fn.flatPrev` should follow..

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data set, you could just flatten the whole thing (presuming `$.find` is stable, which I believe it is), like this:

```
var eles = [];
$("#ul1").find("li").each(function (e) {
    eles.push(e);
});
```

The next element after `ele[3]` is `ele[4]` regardless of the level of indentation.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/xRpmL/